# Sending utf8 contents with post method to server in android using HttpClient

Tags: java, android, http

this is my sample code, however I used HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "utf-8"); im my code but when I send utf-8 data, I receive just "?????" in server side (PHP code)! what is the problem?

```
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "utf-8");

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

    httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8");
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("URL_TO_SERVER");

    try {

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", name.getText().toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uemail", email.getText().toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("udesc", body.getText().toString()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse hresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String response = new Scanner(hresponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();

        hresponse.getEntity().consumeContent();
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

        Log.d("WX", response.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe you should use UTF-8 for the entity:

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 3):

I have worked

```
public static String sendData(String data) {
    String str = null;
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverurl);
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("s", data));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
        str = new Scanner(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();

        Log.v("srv response:", str);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        str = "err2";
    } catch (IOException error) {
        str = "err1.1";
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        str = "err1.2";
    }
    return str;
}
```