# Parse Rest - Push encode message

Tags: parse-platform, react-native, parse-server

I am having issue with push utf8 encode message using Parse Rest, here is my body

```
{"where":{"$and":[{"email":{"$in":["phaxxx@gmail.com","nhungxxx@gmail.com"]}},{"deviceType":{"$in":["ios"]}}]},"data":{"alert":"TEST: Giảm 40% Khi Mua Sách Harry Potter","sound":"default","page_type":"cms_key","page_value":"harry-potter"}}
```

Does anyone know how to encode utf8 message?

[image]

Comment: are u sure that what u see is not a charsets def problem on the device that u show the screendump of?   parseServer and mongoDB backing may both handle utf8 correctly but the handset is using ISO when the bytes provided by backend are using utf8?

Comment: I am sure that my phone is not having character set problem. I regularly having notifications from other apps in Vietnamese language.

Comment: Thang, what do you use as your REST-client when you send notifications? Are you sure that there is no issues with `JSON` encoding in that part of your pipeline?

Comment: @SergGr: Thank you. That is the problem. I resolve the issue using solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322002/how-to-send-string-by-http-post-in-utf-8 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964291/sending-utf8-contents-with-post-method-to-server-in-android-using-httpclient as my rest client is in java

Answer (score 2):

Javascript code:

```
public bool SendPushNotification(string jsonContent)
{
...

    request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", appId);
    request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-KEY", restApiKey);

    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(jsonContent);

...
}
```

Comment: Did it help you @thang-pham?